# Open UIImagePickerController when view loads

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller, uistoryboard

I have a UIViewController, that I would like upon loading the view - to open a UIImagePickerController for the camera.

A. I wrote the following: 
EDITED - I am using now viewDidAppear

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    if([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]){
        [imagePicker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
    }
    else{
        [imagePicker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
    }
    [imagePicker setDelegate:self];
    [self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];
}
```

the problem is, that after the user takes a snap shot or selects an image from folder - it keeps on loading the UIImagePicker again - how can I make it call it only once?

B. I would like the camera to be displayed inside a rectangle (could be UIImage or UIView) and not full screen so I will be able to leave my top navigation bar.

How can I achieve the above?

Comment: You can't do this with an image picker, you'll have to create a capture session with the camera as the input device and display it in a custom view. http://www.musicalgeometry.com/?p=1273

Comment: Kind of both. For "A" I would recommend you do this in viewDidAppear to avoid wait_fence errors, and "B" can not be done using an image picker.

Comment: Is there a way to display the camera inside a frame, without buttons? so the buttons will be the regular camera's buttons

Comment: viewDidAppear - see my edited question keeps on loading the UIImagePicker

Answer (score 1):

For case A, better put this in `viewDidAppear` instead of `viewWillAppear` to avoid animation collisions (and wait_fences error)

For case B, you either need a capture session, or need to tweek the `UIImagePickerController` using a transform. You can do that thanks to the follow `UIImagePickerController` properties:

- [`cameraViewTransform`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIImagePickerController/cameraViewTransform) to change the `CGAffineTransform` applied to the view that displays the camera/video. Thus you will be able to scale it down for example
- [`showsCameraControls`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIImagePickerController/showsCameraControls) that you can set to `NO` to hide the default iOS controls if you plan to add your own `UIButtons` instead
- [`cameraOverlayView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIImagePickerController/cameraOverlayView) that allows you to put an arbitrary `UIView` atop of the camera view. You typically use a view that has a `backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]` and add some subviews to it, especially some decorative `UIImageView` if needed (a frame for example), some `UIButton`s to trigger the camera (and use the `takePicture`, `startVideoCapture` and `stopVideoCapture` methods of `UIImagePickerController` in their corresponding `IBAction` as needed) and replace the build-it camera controls you hid with the previous property, and so on

In your case, if you want to keep the regular camera's button but just want to change the frame and make it not-fullscreen, the `cameraTransform` property is then typically what you need. Adding a decorative frame around will simply consist of using an `UIImageView` for the `cameraOverlayView` property and use it to display the image of the decorative frame (image with its center transparent so that the camera view is visible thru it, of course)

---

[EDIT] Note that (according to the documentation) the `cameraTransform` property is only available when capturing movies (when `sourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera`). So you can use it to let the user take a picture from its camera, but if you want to use your `UIImagePickerController` to choose a picture from the Library, you can't use the `cameraTransform` (and that quite logical, as it would seem strange to display onscreen). So be sure to use it only in that case, and especially avoid it when the `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera` source type is not available on the device.

Comment: viewWillApepar keeps on loading it non stop - after the user captures the image or chooses one from the library, it loads it again

Comment: Of course, you have to use some condition. Typically, once the user has captured the image, you probably keep it in a `@property UIImage* chosenImage;` of your `UIViewController`, so you can use `if (self.chosenImage == nil)` as a condition to show the `UIImagePickerController` in `viewDidAppear` ;)

Comment: Thanks. regarding cameraOverlayView - do you have an code example how to do it?

Comment: Not right there, but GIYF ;) Now that you know the property name, you should find plenty of examples. But still, you can simply create an UIView, set its backgroundColor to the clearColor to make it transparent, and add some subviews to it (e.g. create an UIButton and use `addSubview:` to add it to your transparent view), and finally set the cameraOverlayView property to this transparent view that has your button in it. That's that simple.

Comment: I did as you suggested: 1. Added @property UIImageView* chosenImage; in the .h class 2. in method didFinishPickingImage added  [self.chosenImage setImage:image]; 3, in viewDidAppear have the condition:  if (self.chosenImage == nil) but it's always nil no matter if he chose an image or not

Comment: You should store and test the image, not the imageView

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16323/discussion-between-odelya-and-alisoftware)

Comment: Here is my question: Thanks you were right, but regarding the layer - I looked around, and created a UIView but when I do cameraView.hidden = YES; 
imagePicker.cameraOverlayView = (UIView *) cameraView;

Answer (score 1):

Just implement your action into the viewDidLoad method. This is what I did and it works perfectly fine now.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self getMediaFromSource:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];

}
- (IBAction)TakePhoto:(id)sender {
    [self getMediaFromSource:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
}

- (void)getMediaFromSource:(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType)sourceType{
    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init]; 
    picker.delegate         = self; 
    picker.allowsEditing        = NO; 
    picker.sourceType           = sourceType; 
    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];

    [picker release];
}

#pragma mark - UIImagePickerController delegate methods
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1];
}
- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker { 

    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1];
}
```

Updated Part B.
Example code of cameraOverlayView

```
- (void)setupImagePicker:(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType)sourceType
 {
    self.imagePickerController.sourceType = sourceType;

if (sourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera)
{
    // user wants to use the camera interface
    //
    self.imagePickerController.showsCameraControls = NO;

    if ([[self.imagePickerController.cameraOverlayView subviews] count] == 0)
    {
        // setup our custom overlay view for the camera
        //
        // ensure that our custom view's frame fits within the parent frame
        CGRect overlayViewFrame = self.imagePickerController.cameraOverlayView.frame;
        CGRect newFrame = CGRectMake(0.0,
                                     CGRectGetHeight(overlayViewFrame) -
                                     self.view.frame.size.height - 10.0,
                                     CGRectGetWidth(overlayViewFrame),
                                     self.view.frame.size.height + 10.0);
        self.view.frame = newFrame;
        [self.imagePickerController.cameraOverlayView addSubview:self.view];
    }
 }
}
```

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PhotoPicker/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010196

I would suggest playing with the "cameraOverlayView," to try and create some sort of pseudo navigation bar in which the interaction will work as you intended.

"You can customize an image picker controller to manage user interactions yourself. To do this, provide an overlay view containing the controls you want to display, and use the methods described in “Capturing Still Images or Movies.” You can display your custom overlay view in addition to, or instead of, the default controls. Custom overlay views for the UIImagePickerController class are available in iOS 3.1 and later by way of the cameraOverlayView property. For a code example, see the PhotoPicker sample code project.

Important The UIImagePickerController class supports portrait mode only. This class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified, with one exception. You can assign a custom view to the cameraOverlayView property and use that view to present additional information or manage the interactions between the camera interface and your code."

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html

Comment: Your solution is for A .but what about B?

Comment: So I'm not sure the pickercontrol can do do what you are asking for B. See above update.